# How can I Get the results of the nested query in the form of entities with EF

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

> I have some models in my project:
>
> ```
> **Model ServiceDeliveryDoc**
> ```

```
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PartnerDocId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string LegalEntityId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("LegalEntityId")]
    [InverseProperty("ServiceDeliveryDoc")]
    public LegalEntity LegalEntity { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ServiceDeliveryDoc")]
    public ICollection<ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc> ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc { get; set; }
```

> ```
> **Model ServiceRegistry**
> ```

```
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ServiceRegistry")]
    public ICollection<ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc> ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc { get; set; }
```

> ```
> **Model ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc**
> ```

```
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ServiceRegistryId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDeliveryDocId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ServiceDeliveryDocId")]
    [InverseProperty("ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc")]
    public ServiceDeliveryDoc ServiceDeliveryDoc { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ServiceRegistryId")]
    [InverseProperty("ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc")]
    public ServiceRegistry ServiceRegistry { get; set; }
```

> I write some nested query in SQL to get ServiceDeliveryDoc with
>   LegalEntity, filtered by ServiceRegistryId:

```
SELECT  ReturnsTable.[Id]
        ,ReturnsTable.[PartnerDocId]
        ,ReturnsTable.[Date]
        ,ReturnsTable.[Cost]
        ,ReturnsTable.[LegalEntityId]
        ,LegalEntityTable.[Name]
        ,ReturnsTable.[DocProcessId]
 FROM [Vishnya].[dbo].[ServiceDeliveryDoc] as ReturnsTable
 left join [Vishnya].[dbo].[LegalEntity] as LegalEntityTable
 on ReturnsTable.[LegalEntityId] = LegalEntityTable.[Id]
 where ReturnsTable.Id in ( select ServiceDeliveryDocId
                            from ServiceRegistry_To_ServiceDeliveryDoc
                            where ServiceRegistryId = @ServiceRegistryId)
```

How I can recieve simular result, using Enity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your SQL query and the model design , there is a one-to-one relationship between `ServiceDeliveryDoc` and `LegalEntity` , many-to-many relationship between `ServiceDeliveryDoc` and `ServiceRegistry` . For [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) , you could use include like below:

```
var result = _context.ServiceDeliveryDoc
            .Include(sd => sd.LegalEntity)
            .Where(sd =>
                _context.ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc
                    .Where(srt => srt.ServiceRegistryId == "101")
                    .Select(srt => srt.ServiceDeliveryDocId)
                    .Contains(sd.Id)
            )
            .Select(sd => new
            {
                sd.Id,sd.PartnerDocId , sd.Date,sd.Cost,sd.LegalEntityId, sd.LegalEntity.Name
            }).ToList();
```

DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{       
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc>()
            .HasOne(sr => sr.ServiceDeliveryDoc)
            .WithMany(sd => sd.ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc)
            .HasForeignKey(sr => sr.ServiceDeliveryDocId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc>()
           .HasOne(sr => sr.ServiceRegistry)
           .WithMany(sd => sd.ServiceRegistryToServiceDeliveryDoc)
           .HasForeignKey(sr => sr.ServiceRegistryId);

}
```